# Android Update Screen before task

Tags: android, screen, android-alertdialog

I have the following problem: I am executing a task and want during execution an AlertDialog to be displayed.
So this is the idea I have had:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
builder.setMessage("Please hold while we're doing stuff");
final AlertDialog tAD = builder.create();
tAD.setCancelable(false);
tAD.show();
for(int t1 = 0; t1 < 1000000; t1++); //doing stuff simulation
//tAD.dismiss();
```

But the AlertDialog gets displayed AFTER the loop. Is there any function to "flush" or "update" the screen or pending Android tasks?

Comment: This does not make any sense since you are calling it in same Ui thread . Also your code is incomplete to make any comment . Consider using  [AsyncTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do such tasks in worker `thread` as in

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
builder.setMessage("Please hold while we're doing stuff");
final AlertDialog tAD = builder.create();
tAD.setCancelable(false);
tAD.show();
new Thread(new Runnable(){
 @Override
  public void run(){
   for(int t1 = 0; t1 < 5; t1++)
         Thread.sleep(1000); //doing stuff simulation for 5 seconds
   runOnUIThread(new Runnable(){
          @Override
          public void run(){
            tAD.dismiss();
          });
  }
 }).start();
```